# Python: What is a 'from import * safe' module?

Tags: python, module, namespaces

I'm looking at "Idioms and Anti-Idioms in Python" in the [part](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#when-it-is-just-fine) where it talks about the situation when a module "advertises itself as `from import *` safe".

What are examples of modules that are safe in this sense?  I think this sense is different from a module being simply 'import safe' (no from, no star).

Why would one want a module to be safe in this sense?

Comment: So the namespace doesn't shadow functions with the same names.

Comment: @jamylak - unless no other `import *`-safe module exposes objects of the same names ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that it does not use names that are commonly used by other modules including the `__builtin__` module.  For example, a module would not be safe if it had "def ord(x)" or "def int(x)" because those are python builtins.

Comment: It also means, that the module makes explicit mention of the "public" names (those that are imported) in it's \__all__ attribute